# Creating a Connection Between MySQL and Tornado

Tags: python, mysql, tornado, python-2.7

I am trying to get a Python and Tornado environment up and running.

As of now I am able to execute Python scripts and now I am trying to be able to make use of databases as well.

By my understanding Tornado has a MySQL wrapper, and I as of now I have XAMPP installed and I would like to continue using PhpMyAdmin as the GUI for MySQL.

The question I am having is how can I create a connection between MySQL and Tornado?

So that when you use a connection command Tornado will connect to the right MySQL installation and databases, which I of course created with PhpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 3):

From Tornado's [documentation](https://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/branch2.4/database.html):

```
db = database.Connection("localhost", "mydatabase")
```

Once you instantiate a connection ( named db in this example ), you can reuse it during your server's lifetime..

If you need to change it dynamically while your tornado server is running, then have tornado "listen" to a specific url_pattern, handled by the appropriate web.RequestHandler, which receives as (GET or POST) arguments your MYSQL connection parameters (host, database, user etc..) and creates a new database connection.

**Edit**

In newer versions of tornado (>=3.0) the tornado.database module has been removed. It is now available as a separate package, [torndb](https://github.com/bdarnell/torndb).

Comment: The thing I am wondering is will Tornado find the MySQL installation that easily? Or do I need to copy and paste a file? Because as said I am using XAMPP, thus the MySQL installation folder is in the XAMPP folder, and the databases I create are saved in the MySQL folder. Will Tornado be able to know where to find the database? In which location et cetera?

Comment: Your MySQL database is a server running on a host, regardless of the package (XAMPP) that is part of. The connection parameters are unaware of that. Have you tried something that didn't work?

Comment: I think a configuration in the application must be done so Tornado knows where to look at for MySQL, obviously it is not going to search my whole computer for it, and I am wondering where the configuration is done. Any ideas?

Comment: @Carpet: In case you're still confused 3.5 years later, MySQL has a standard port it runs on (I forget what it is ATM...). Tornado knows that and accesses your database using that standard port.

Comment: The link to the documentation appears to be dead. Does Tornato still have a database module or was it removed at some point in the 3.5 years since this was posted? I see no mention of it in the current documentation...

Comment: Ah, thanks for the update. I'll +1 now. Although as an aside, are you familiar with Meteor.com? I discovered it in the time from when I was investigating Tornado and now, and I think I'll be going with them because it looks like they provide tools for extremely rapidly making both server and client prototypes.

Comment: Yes, meteor is cool and I'd like to use it for future projects. For the moment I am full stack python (Django, Tornado) because I feel more confident and surrounded by mature tools. But yes Javascript frameworks are hot!